# Ubuntu 14.04 - Unable to type Unicode / rupee sign

Tags: 14.04, unicode-entry

I was able to insert Rupee sign (`₹`) using the Alt-R + 4 key combination, but now I'm unable to do so. I'm not able to feed any other Unicode char using the `Ctrl + Shift + U` combination either.

I don't know whether its some update or something that has led to this issue.

**System**: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
**Desktop**: Unity

Strangely, my iBus daemon too starts up with Unity. I've tried quitting it and trying to feed the Unicode, but to no avail !

Comment: Did you uninstall some packages recently? Can you check your apt or software center log?

Comment: Nops, nothing specific for transliteration or keyboards. But yes!, there are tons of updates and corresponding installs that have happend.

Comment: Same here, `Shift+Ctrl+U` does not work in 14.04, like it is said here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Unicode_composition

Comment: See [potentially related question/answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209293/mint-17-cinnamon-ctrlshiftu-not-letting-me-enter-unicode-symbols) re: unicode entry